# Should we make a review of geology related tags on posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Well I have time, I do not know a lot of the tags beneficts but it looks important for correctly search for information.

Lots of [examples where they are not correctly tagged](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16507/how-can-i-identify-tough-mixed-granites) when we talk about geology.

Should I edit the posts to correctly classify the info?

The trouble I see is my editions would need to be reviewed and some ancient questions will appear at active list if I review them.

I wonder too [if I should add tags that are deduced from the answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16702/what-are-these-basal-rip-up-clasts-in-north-dakota) and not from the question. (Imagine "What is this? I tag is as geology "It is a rock, then tagged as petrology too).

Answer (score 1):

As the subject of the question is not going to be changed, I think I am gonna do it with some order and in groups of 3 each day, changing only when it is clear and obvious and avoiding bad questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should feel free to edit tags every time you find it appropriate. If you have time to do so, it would be a great service to the community.

I've reviewed the tagging of the questions I've answered a few time and I do find annoying that all those questions get bumped to the top of the active questions list.

In Meta I saw other people complaining about the same thing, but it seem like the people behind SE thinks that is a desirable behaviour. And to be fare is not a big deal.

I would suggest that you go ahead with all the retagging you find is necessary, ideally doing it in very large or very small batches. If you do a lot of questions in one go you will monopolize the list of active questions just a few times. On the other hand, if you do it just a couple question at a time. It would be a nice way to boost the activity of the site and it won't bury other questions too deep in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I am reviewing the questions related to geology and then I will simply retag new questions I see incorrectly tagged. [I asked it in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364329/995796) and it is ok to do so. I encourage users to do so to better order the info we are managing.

I will follow Camilo Rada's advice and only review 3 questions each day not to monopolize the list of active questions and not to flood the review queue.